# Spring cloud sleuth Propagating Span Context

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

I am trying to add span context like below, with spring boot 2.0 and sleuth version 2.0.RC1/2.0.RC2

```
Span initialSpan = _tracer.nextSpan().name("span").start();
try( Tracer.SpanInScope ws = _tracer.withSpanInScope(initialSpan) ) {
    ExtraFieldPropagation.set("foo", "bar");
    ExtraFieldPropagation.set("UPPER_CASE", "someValue");
}
```

after setting the data when trying to retrieve getting null value

```
ExtraFieldPropagation.get("foo")
```

Comment: That might be related to https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/issues/682

Comment: Do you retrieve the key in the same method or in another service?

Comment: I have to retrieve in different service, but for testing purpose doing in same method and still getting null.

Comment: The same method won't work IMO - check this out https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sleuth-documentation-apps here we set the baggage https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sleuth-documentation-apps/blob/master/service1/src/main/java/io/spring/cloud/sleuth/docs/service1/Service2Client.java#L50 and here we retrieve it https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sleuth-documentation-apps/blob/master/service2/src/main/java/io/spring/cloud/sleuth/docs/service2/Application.java#L87 and it works fine `Service2Controller    : Service2: Baggage for [key] is [foo]`

Comment: when i observed the code, find(context.extra()) is always returning empty even after set.
please find the below class and method.

public abstract class PropagationFields {}

public static void put(TraceContext context, String name, String value) {
    if (context == null) throw new NullPointerException("context == null");
    if (name == null) throw new NullPointerException("name == null");
    if (value == null) throw new NullPointerException("value == null");
    PropagationFields fields = find(context.extra());
    if (fields == null) return;
    fields.put(name, value);
  }

Comment: I have no idea what this comment means. Maybe let's move it to gitter? https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract